# Store CLion build profile in repository

Tags: cmake, clion

I am wondering if there is a way to store the build profiles of CLion in the repository so that all team members can use the same profile?

I am talking about the build profiles in`Settings/Build/CMake`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CLion 2021.1 there will be possibility to share your CMake profile settings. The new option is available in *Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake*.
When `Share` is enabled the settings will be stored in `.idea/cmake.xml` which you can simply add to VCS.
[image]